# Asp.net MVC Unauthorized status code and RedirectResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an authorization filter which checks if users session is valid.

```
public class ValidateSessionTokenFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_SessionTokenIsValid() == false)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(_LoginUrl(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if setting the status code to `Unauthorized` and then returning a `RedirectResult` is making a conflict?

Should i just return a `RedirectResult` without specifying the `Unauthorized` status code?

Answer (score 0):

you use formsauthentication?

you can try this,

```
 if (authorizationContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    return;
                }

                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```